# Looping through an HTML node structure

Tags: c#, html

I have loaded an `HTML` page in C# using the `HtmlDocument` `LoadHtml` method. I am trying to move through the `HTML` structure. The local `HTML` snippet that I am targeting is the following:

```
<tr class="xxxx">
    <td class="yyyy">
        <span>Key-content</span>
        <sup class ="zzzz">abcd</sup>
    </td>
    <td class="wwww">Value-content</td>
</tr>
```

Using `DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode` in C#, I would like to get hold of the element content 'Value-content' (that actually corresponds to the element content 'Key-content') using the parameter that I know, which is the 'Key-content' string. I am struggling to write down the correct `XPath` string.

I have tried this:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.GetAsync(address, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
using (HttpResponseMessage message = response.Result)
{
    using (HttpContent content = message.Content)
    {
        string xmlData = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(xmlData);

        string xpath = "//*['Key-content']/../../td[1]";
        // ==> //*['Key-content']: to reach the node <span> that contains 'Key-content'.
        // ==> /../..: to move back up twice to the node <tr>.
        // ==> /td[1]: to move down to the targeted node.
        HtmlNode node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
        string text = node.InnerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your best attempt that didn't work.

Comment: @Fidor. I have enclosed my (feeble) attempt: I am a beginner in this field...

Comment: Index in xpath is 1-based, so try a `td[2]`

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Hans Keﬆing. I will try this. Do you reckon the rest of the path `"//*['Key-content']/../.."` is correct to go where I want?

Comment: You could try parts of that path, to see whether you end up where you expected. But at first glance it looks OK

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing. The path prefix `"//*['Key-content']` does not get me where I need: it seems to leave me under the top root `<html>`.

Comment: instead of `['Key-content']`, try `[text()='Key-content']`

Comment: Thank you @Hans Keﬆing. Actually, I am faced with a parsing issue: I get a null node that results from an `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.DepthLevelExceptionMessage = "The document is too complex to parse"`. I am not sure how I can tackle this...